# How to display Custom Post Type for specific post IDs

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm new to wordpress and am working on a custom post type called RankThem. Members rank by numbers (through gravity form submission) their top 5 editorials each week. I want to display the members profile picture, name and their submitted ranking number specific to the post ID, each editorial will have it's on post ID. I've been working to write a function for each data-output but have not been successful. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function get_rankthem_post_types()
{
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'=>'rankthem'
    );
    $_PostID = get_posts($args);

    /*string to return*/
    $content = '';

    foreach($_PostID as $key=>$val)
    {
        $content .= '<strong>'.$val->user_id.'</strong><br />'; 
        $content .= $val->user_avatar.'<hr />'; 
        $content .= $val->post_content.'<hr />';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: hey get_posts return an array of post so you have to loop through it twice, once for each post and then again to access the data of each post such as the user_avatar etc. Also it can be empty if it doesn't have any post.

Comment: Yikes! it didn't work. Ended up locking me out of admin and had to remove the file by FTP before my password was accepted. Any idea why that happened?

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_rankthem_post_types()
{
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'=>'rankthem'
    );

    //this will be an array of posts
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    /*string to return*/
    $content = '';

    foreach ($posts as $post)
     {
      foreach($post as $key => $val)
      {
        $content .= '<strong>'.$val->user_id.'</strong><br />'; 
        $content .= $val->user_avatar.'<hr />'; 
        $content .= $val->post_content.'<hr />';
      }
    }

    return $content;
}
```